# Hashing the code of a Python function (including lambdas)

Tags: python, hash, lambda

I'm trying to make a simple intermediate compilation function:

```
lst = [lambda x: calculate_urls(),
       lambda x: join_urls_with_ids(x, args[0]),
       lambda x: bucket_urls(x)]
intermediate.execute(lst)
```

`intermediate.execute` will run each item in the list. The first function's output is the second function's input, and so on. The lambdas are used to make each function take only one argument. (The first input value is `None`, so it's effectively ignored here.)

At each intermediate step the output is pickled and saved (currently just to `/tmp`). If some intermediate output already exists for a function, execution of the function is skipped and it goes onto the next step.

I'm looking for a way to detect changes in the function code, and I figured hashing the code would be a quick way of doing that. I want it to detect if someone changed the implementation of a function, so that it would execute the function again and ignore the cached value.

I found out about `func_code`, which is hashable AFAIK. However, it only works for that particular function, which means that the hash only changes if the lambdas in the code above  change, not the functions being called by the lambdas. Is what I'm looking for theoretically possible? Is there a reasonable middle ground?

Comment: "detect if someone changed the implementation of a function" Someone cannot "change the implementation" of a function. You either have the same function object or a different function object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing lambdas, you could store lists of function-argument tuples, and hash the `func_code` of those functions.  That is, instead of what you have, do:

```
lst = [
    (calculate urls, ()),
    (join_urls_with_ids, (args[0])),
    (bucket_urls, ())
]
```

Then make `intermediate.execute` be like:

```
def execute(lst):
    result = ()
    for func, args in list:
        args = result + args
        result = func(*args)
```

However, it's a little hard to grasp what you're trying to do here.  Is the idea that the function implementations might change between different invocations of the program?  (That is, run, save cache, exit, change the source code of `calculate_urls`, then run again?)  If so, you might be better off hashing the function's source code instead (using `inspect.getsource`).  Python bytecode (which is what's in `func_code`) is not really a stable target and could change between Python versions.

Comment: +1 for using the source code to avoid instabilities due to different Python versions. Note that the source code may not be available (built-in functions, compiled modules without source file, etc.).

Comment: @FlorianBrucker: Yes, but if the source code isn't available, then it's reasonable to assume it won't change (or at least, that changes to it are outside the scope of what this cache mechanism can reasonably handle).

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, that's the basic idea. Ideally there would be a way to hash based on the source of the function, every function it calls, every function those functions call, etc, at least if the function source is accessible. But that might not be feasible

Answer (score 0):

How about making a backup list of the functions? If something changes one of them in lst, the lists won't be equal any more.

```
lst = [lambda x: calculate_urls(),
       lambda x: join_urls_with_ids(x, args[0]),
       lambda x: bucket_urls(x)]
backup = list(lst)

lst[0] = lambda x: foo()

if lst != backup:
    print("Something changed")
```